# Why am I having a conflict between two StaticResource on the same control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following markup declared in my control's resources:

```
<conv:ActionItemToBooleanConverter x:Key="ActionItemToBooleanConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton  Content="Foo2"
                                  GroupName="FOo"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding CurrentProcessPoint, Converter={StaticResource ActionItemToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For the RadioButton, when I introduced the `Converter={StaticResource ActionItemToBooleanConverter}` on my `IsChecked` Property it suddenly caused a problem for my `Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"`. A blue squiggly appears under the style and says 'The resource {x:Type ToggleButton} could not be resolved'.

Why is this happening? What is it about the introduction of a StaticResource for my Converter that prevents me from Styling my RadioButton as a ToggleButton?

What can I add/fix to resolve the conflict?

Thanks

Comment: does it work at run-time?

Comment: In VS 2012, sometimes the designer shows an error when there really isn't. It's a royal pain sometimes.  If the code compiles & runs when you hit F5, you're good.

Comment: @Omribitan It does indeed work at run-time. So if its a VS2012 design-time issue then so be it. I just find it peculiar and would like to know why exactly these kinds of errors happen. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: If you close the XAML, are the errors still there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild de project and see what happens.